# Add labels to metpy skewt lines

Tags: python, metpy

I am trying to add labels to the lines on a skewt diagram using metpy. I'm not sure if it possible (looked at the GitHub for metpy and seems like they haven't yet implemented this ability). But essentially I just want to have labels for moist adiabats, dry adiabats, and mixing ratio. Currently, the code I use to call and plot these functions is:

```
# Choose temperatures for moist adiabats
t0 = units.K * np.arange(278.15, 306.15, 4)
msa = skew.plot_moist_adiabats(t0=t0, linestyles='solid', colors='lime', linewidths=1.5)
```

```
# Choose starting temperatures in Kelvin for the dry adiabats
t0 = units.K * np.arange(243.15, 443.15, 10)
skew.plot_dry_adiabats(t0=t0,
                         linestyles='solid',
                         colors='gray',
                         linewidth=1.5)
```

and

```
# Choose the range of pressures that the mixing ratio lines are drawn over
p = units.hPa * np.linspace(1000, 400, 7)
skew.plot_mixing_lines(w=w, p=p, colors='lime')
```

Answer (score 0):

MetPy does not currently have the ability to automatically label those special lines. As I'm sure you found, there is currently an [open issue](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues/890) for that. Right now your best solution is to use the `ax.text` method to add the text manually on the plot, calculating the dewpoint at the top of the line to position the text:

```
import metpy.calc as mpcalc
from metpy.plots import SkewT
from metpy.units import units

skew = SkewT()

w = np.array([0.028, 0.024, 0.020, 0.016, 0.012, 0.008, 0.004])[:, None] * units('g/g')
p = units.hPa * np.linspace(1000, 400, 7)
skew.plot_mixing_lines(w=w, p=p, colors='lime')

# Label every third line
for val in w.flatten()[::3]:
    top_p = p[-1]
    dewpt = mpcalc.dewpoint(mpcalc.vapor_pressure(top_p, val))
    skew.ax.text(dewpt, top_p, str(val.to('g/kg').m),
                 horizontalalignment='center')
```